# Can I request garden leave when I've been given 3 months notice with little reason?

Tags: united-kingdom, layoff

I work in the UK in the hospitality sector. I have been told that there isn't enough revenue coming into the company to facilitate the salary for my role anymore and I have been given 3 months notice (my contracted notice period.) My manager wasn't clear if this is redundancy or performance based, simply citing a 'restructure'.

I want to apply for [garden leave](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97348/why-is-garden-leave-so-called) so I can look for a new role full-time.
Am I allowed to do this and what's the likelihood it will get granted?

Comment: This may be dependent on both local labor law and on industry. Please add more information.

Comment: If you are being made redundant, you may be entitled to redundancy pay.  The comapny may be trying to avoid paying it to you.  https://www.gov.uk/redundancy-your-rights/redundancy-pay

Comment: How many years service do you have, how many people are being made redundant  and  have they followed to the letter their redundancy procedure (they do have a redundancy procedure?)  as @DaveGremlin says they might be doing you out of statutory redundancy

Answer (score 17):

> I want to apply for garden leave so I can look for a role. Am I
>   allowed to do this and what's the likelihood it will get granted?

You certainly can ask, but don't keep your hopes up. It gives you the upside of 3 months paid leave, and downside to the company of having to pay you, but also not getting anything out of you. Hardly a fair deal.

Now if you were to offer them something in the middle, like offering to halve the notice period in exchange for garden leave, you just gave them incentive of only having to pay you for a month and a half, in exchange for no work expectations. And that is something that is way more likely to succeed.

Some other strategies may be to agree to some "afternoons off" with a reduction of hours, so you can then interview in those time slots, and then pick up the work in the evening (if feasible). If you will try to make a negotiation out of it, where both sides try to compromise on something that is even, you will likely have a greater chance of succeeding.
This is also probably a good time to confirm if they would be interested in releasing you from the notice period earlier, assuming that you land a new job quickly. A great reference letter would help with that, so also about the best time to ask for one. And all part of bargaining you can strike with the boss.

Answer (score 4):

You can ask but it is very unlikely. The company gains nothing from having you not come to work, and they still have to pay you. Garden leave is for situations where there is an advantage to you not coming in - perhaps because your role has the potential to damage the company, or your replacement wants a clean break, or you've done something so embarrassing the company doesn't want you around.

What you can do is offer something to the company in exchange for the time off - for example take two months pay instead of three if you don't have to come in.